# Can I track the keys pressed, using ActionScript?

Tags: flash, actionscript, keylistener

Can I track the keys pressed, using ActionScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this class that I made a while back:

**EDIT**: Slightly cleaner now.

```
    package
    {
        import flash.display.Stage;
        import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

        public class Keys extends Object
        {
            // vars
            private var _keys:Array = [];

            /**
             * Constrcutor
             * @param stg The stage to apply listeners to
             */
            public function Keys(stg:Stage)
            {
                stg.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, _keydown);
                stg.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, _keyup);
            }

            /**
             * Called on dispatch of KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN
             */
            private function _keydown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                //trace(e.keyCode);
                _keys[e.keyCode] = true;
            }

            /**
             * Called on dispatch of KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP
             */
            private function _keyup(e:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                delete _keys[e.keyCode];
            }

            /**
             * Returns a boolean value that represents a given key being held down or not
             * @param ascii The ASCII value of the key to check for
             */
            public function isDown(...ascii):Boolean
            {
                var i:uint;
                for each(i in ascii)
                {
                    if(_keys[i]) return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

It's simple from here: create an instance of keys and use the isDown() method.

```
    var keys:Keys = new Keys(stage);

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _handle);
    function _handle(e:Event):void
    {
         if(keys.isDown(65)) trace('key A is held down');
    }
```

It can even check for multiple keys at once:

```
if(keys.isDown(65, 66)) // true if 'a' or 'b' are held down.
```

**EDIT:**

It also helps a lot when you're testing using compile (ctrl+enter) to disable keyboard shortcuts (control -> disable keyboard shortcuts).

Comment: Why does Keys extends Sprite?

Comment: Because Object doesn't have a stage property as it's not a DisplayObject.

Comment: @miguelSantirso How does that suit you?

Comment: But, in the code you posted, the stage property is passed as a parameter to the class constructor so I don't see why you need to extend Sprite...

Comment: Stage wasn't parsed to the constructor when Keys was extending Sprite - this was all one amend - see edits.